# Transit in Ho Chi Minh City

Tags: transit-visas, sgn

I have a flight from Abu Dhabi and will transit at Ho Chi Minh City, Vietnam, arriving at 18.30. The onward flight to Manila, Philippines is the next day at 09.00.

Can I leave the airport to see my boyfriend and if I can, do I need a visa?

Comment: What is your citizenship?

Answer (score 1):

If, guessing from your itinerary, you are Filipino, then you do not need a visa to enter Vietnam for that period of time.  But keep in mind, by entering the country, you then become liable for any departure taxes imposed by Vietnam.

If you hold other citizenship, then we will need to know which before any definite answers can be given.